Autocomplete MUI v5 - value doesn't get selected when I try to select any option
This is my component using MUI's autocomplete.
When I use this component in the UI, I try to select one option, but I don't see the option in the autocomplete TextField.
Looks like the controlledValue was updated well, but the issue still exists.
The component:
const Autocomplete = forwardRef(
  (
    {
      id,
      options,
      placeholder,
      inputValue,
      onChange,
      onSelect,
      disabled,
      maxOptions,
      isLoading,
      freeText = false,
      open: incomingOpen,
      ...rest
    },
    ref
  ) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [controlledInputValue, setControlledInputValue] = useState(inputValue || '');
    const [controlledValue, setControlledValue] = useState(options[0]);

    const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
      limit: maxOptions
    });

    const handleInputChange = (event, newInputValue, reason) => {
      if (reason === 'input') {
        setOpen(true);
        setControlledInputValue(newInputValue)
      } else {
        setOpen(false);
      }

      if (onChange) {
        onChange();
      }
    
    };

    const handleOptionChange = (event, selectedValue) => {
      const selectedOption = options.find(option => option === selectedValue);
      setControlledValue(selectedOption);

      setOpen(false);
      
      if (onSelect) {
        onSelect();
      }
    };

    return (
      <Autocomplete
        id={id}
        ref={ref}
        data-qa-id="autocomplete"
        options={options}
        autoHighlight={true} 
        popupIcon={null} 
        size="small"
        disabled={disabled}
        freeSolo={freeText}
        filterOptions={filterOptions}
        open={incomingOpen ? incomingOpen : open}
        loading={isLoading}
        inputValue={controlledInputValue}
        onInputChange={handleInputChange}
        value={controlledValue}
        onChange={handleOptionChange}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            placeholder={disabled ? 'text' : placeholder}
            variant="outlined"
            ref={params.InputProps.ref}
            InputProps={{
              ...params.InputProps,
              startAdornment: (
                <>
                  {params.InputProps.startAdornment}
                  <SearchIcon disabled={disabled} />
                </>
              )
            }}
          />
        )}
        {...rest}
      />
    );
  }
);

Autocomplete.displayName = 'Autocomplete';

export default Autocomplete;

The code that uses the component:
export const Auto = () => {

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="Autocomplete"
      placeholder="Search"
      options={['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']}
    />
  );
};

I try to use isOptionEqualToValue property - but it did not help.
